# Menu block doesn't appears where I expect it

Tags: routes, blocks

I have this kind of menu:
"Level 1" has menu item "Level 2", which links to the page with "cat1" url. Then, I have node which have aliases "cat1/[nid]", hence, in my opinion, menu block (provided by "menu block" [module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)) should appear. But it doesn't. Why?

If you haven't worked with menu block module and not familliar with it, then how can I force to show "Level 1 -> Level 2" menu part if a node with alias "cat1/[nid]" is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the code of the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, I understood this module doesn't work with URLs. There are other modules, such as the [Context: Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/context_menu_block) module, which make it possible.

> Context: Menu Block allows the Menu Block module to be aware of contexts provided by the Context module by informing menu blocks of active menu context reactions.